# How do I prevent people from exploiting my Rest Api

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, security, csrf

Lets say I am making a music app, where users can upload musics and listen to them. The plays counter increments if they listen the music for at least 30 sec. So the code would look something like:

```js
private plays_listener(){
        let hasViewsUpdated = false;
        let counter = 0;
        this.audio.addEventListener("timeupdate", ()=>{
            if(!hasViewsUpdated){
                counter += 0.22;
                if(counter > 30){
                    hasViewsUpdated = true;
                    updatePlays()
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

And the `updatePlays` function will send a request to my server and update the plays.

```js
async function updatePlays(){
  await fetch("/api/track/update/plays", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        "CSRF-Token": <string>Cookies.get("XSRF-TOKEN"),
        
      },
      "body": JSON.stringify({song_id: "kjkfsd_aa"})
  })
}
```

But you still can send the same post request to this url from the developer console and the plays can get increased without actually playing the song. Like this:

[image]

So the api will still consider this as a valid request as csrf token and session token will also be sent. So how can i prevent this from happening.

Comment: Why would you believe the *client* what they tell you? Always treat client data as untrusted. That means that any logic like what you have should be on the *server*. The easiest way to go about this is to only allow updating every 30 seconds. Any request that comes *before* the 30 second mark is ignored.

Comment: @VLAZ Couldn't you get like 1,000 serverless instances to query the API every 30 seconds? Or just have one instance, but simulate that you're listening to 1,000 songs (e.g. send 1,000 queries saying you're starting each of those songs, wait 30 seconds, send another query for each song)?

Comment: @Cully I mean, how would you verify that 30 seconds after a user has started to listen to a song, they've actually listened for 30 seconds? What if they only listened to 29 seconds? That's an inherent problem. With that said, why would you allow a user to listen to 1000 songs? Surely, if you're interested in keeping some sort of track, you won't allow that. You'd rate limit listening to song *just like* you'd rate limit how often you'd update the counter. Either allow one song at a time (like Spotify) or perhaps something like 10 at most.

Comment: @VLAZ You didn't include rate limiting in your first comment.

Comment: Some ideas: require an account (login), use nonces, only allow listening to one song at a time, don't allow an "I'm done" request until 30 seconds has passed since the "Started playing" request, stream unique codes (unique to that individual play-through) along with the song and the user has to send those codes with some "I'm still listening" requests while listening.

Comment: @Cully limiting to once per 30 seconds is limiting. The comment is meant to be, you know, a comment. Not an exhaustive solution. I gave the general principle of "don't trust the client" and an example. I hoped that's enough. Then you retorted with "but what if you trust the client in other cases?".

Comment: @Cully thanks for the idea that your provided, maybe i will use websockets instead of rest api as it suits with the idea you gave.